# how to plot XGBoost evaluation metrics?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, xgboost, xgbclassifier

I've the following code

```
eval_set = [(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test)]
eval_metric = ["auc","error"]
```

In the following part, I'm training the `XGBClassifier` model

```
model = XGBClassifier()
%time model.fit(X_train, y_train, eval_set=eval_set, eval_metric=eval_metric, verbose=True)
```

This gives me the metrics in the following format

```
[0] validation_0-auc:0.840532   validation_0-error:0.187758 validation_1-auc:0.84765    validation_1-error:0.17672
[1] validation_0-auc:0.840536   validation_0-error:0.187758 validation_1-auc:0.847665   validation_1-error:0.17672
....
[99] validation_0-auc:0.917587  validation_0-error:0.13846  validation_1-auc:0.918747   validation_1-error:0.137714
Wall time: 5 s
```

I made a DataFrame out of this and plotted between time (0-99) and the other metrics. Is there any other way to plot directly feeding the output?

Comment: what do you mean _"I made a DataFrame out of this"_? The most straightforward option is to use `model.evals_result()['sample name']['metric name']` list in plotting. See https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#xgboost.XGBClassifier.evals_result for an example

Comment: @MykhailoLisovyi thanks, will check it out. By dataframe, I meant I took the output and created one.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'll continue from your code to show the example of plotting your AUC score.

```
results = model.evals_result()
epochs = len(results['validation_0']['error'])
x_axis = range(0, epochs)
```

**results** is your y-axis values, and **epochs** is your 'n_estimators' value. Code below plots these results:

```
fig, ax = pyplot.subplots()
ax.plot(x_axis, results['validation_0']['auc'], label='Train')
ax.plot(x_axis, results['validation_1']['auc'], label='Test')
ax.legend()
pyplot.ylabel('AUC')
pyplot.title('XGBoost AUC')
pyplot.show()
```

This will then give the following output:

[image: AUC XGBoost evaluation metric plot]

If you want to look at classification error, change ['**auc**'] to ['**error**'] within ax.plot